# Obscure drivers for WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, wifi-driver

*Obscure here is vid 148f pid 2573*

After much googling and a duck duck go session, I have encountered a 404^2 situation, where I can't even *verify the existence* of my device beyond pci-database.com and my actual owning of one. I.E., there's a '404' for a 404. (404^2 - Site/404 not existing?) So I need some windows xp drivers for v148f p2573. All I have to go on is it being a 802.11bg adaptor and (only from pcid) made by "Plant Technologies inc." or something, or "Giggs" for short. (High level abbreviating here, folks) Thinking about it, do such drivers exist in the first place, considering Vista was factory installed to the laptop?

Comment: Might want to add some whitespace and condense others. E.g. who cares if you searches with DuckDuck, google, Bing or something else. Just state that you searched hard but did not found anything but no-longer existing pages.

Comment: @Hennes It was mainly to prove how hard I searched (I admit to expecting a knee-jerk "google harder"), and the last line was question if such a page existed at all

Comment: As to your last question: There might indeed not be drivers for it. XP is ancient (original end of life 2009!). So there simply might not be an XP driver.  Which is rather hard to prove and thus not an answer.

Comment: Adding the link to the PCI database would suffice for proof of searching (at least it would for me).  Creative use of 404^2 for error page not found BTW :)

Comment: Anyone that says "Google harder" should be reported for leaving non-constructive comments

Comment: Pull the wireless card from the PC to see if you can identify the make and model.